# Css transitions issue with changing "style" with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a problem.
I created two blocks, one of them initially invisible. when I click on the link - the hidden block smoothly appears to the right, pushing the left main block. But when I click on the second link, which is to turn everything back, animations do not work. I need that animation ))

My html

```
<div class="content"><a href="#" class="click">CLICK</a></div>
<div class="hidden-content"><a href="#" class="undo-click">UNDO</a></div>
```

My css

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: #fff;
}

.content {
transition: all .5s ease;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
background: red;
}

.hidden-content {
width: 0px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
right: -300px;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: right .5s ease;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
background: blue;
}
```

and js

```
$('.click').click(function(){
$(".content").css('position', 'fixed');
$(".content").css('left', '-300px');
$(".hidden-content").css('visibility', 'visible');
$(".hidden-content").css('opacity', '1');
$(".hidden-content").css('right', '0px');
$(".hidden-content").css('width', '300px');
});

$('.undo-click').click(function(){
$(".content").css('position', 'static');
$(".content").css('left', '0px');
$(".hidden-content").css('visibility', 'hidden');
$(".hidden-content").css('opacity', '0');
$(".hidden-content").css('right', '-300px');
$(".hidden-content").css('width', '0px');
});
```

May be I need jQuery animations? Thanks for any help!

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q283G/)

Comment: this is a very bad way of doing what you're trying to accomplish!

Comment: @AminJafari Show me please good way instead of what would put a minus

Comment: I did not give you a downvote, I'm working on a better way

Comment: Thank you. I just felt that this is the only way that does not interfere with my previous markup

Comment: I added a new answer, I really hope it will help you to understand that HTML is for defining the structure of your site, CSS for the presentation and Javascript (in this case jQuery as a js framework) for behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to avoid to use jQuery to add CSS properties.
Instead add and remove a class with CSS properties applied for instance using toggleClass in jQuery:

```
$('.click').click(function(){
     $(".content").toggleClass('hide');
    $(".hidden-content").toggleClass('show');
});

$('.undo-click').click(function(){
    $(".hidden-content").toggleClass('show');
    $(".content").toggleClass('hide');
});
```

This way you don't really need to use so many lines of jQuery and also to have the animation working correctly you were missing the top:0; in CSS into the hidden-content class.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.content{
    transition: left .5s ease;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
}

.content.hide{
    transition: left .5s ease;
    position:absolute;
    left: -300px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
}

.hidden-content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -300px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    background: blue;
}

.hidden-content.show{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    background: blue;
}
```

Furthermore, when you move a container absolute positioned you don't really need to hide it or change its width since you are moving it away from the viewport you can just leave the width and opacity the same but rely only on the position, editing left, right, top and bottom position of it.

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/q283G/7/

Comment: Look at horizontal scroll please after clicking undo-click.. It no need here.

Comment: Yes, that's a detail. Remove the scroll with overflow-x:hidden. Sorry if i removed it but i was modifying your jsfiddle quickly. :)

Comment: I have edited the jsfiddle and my answer. Add overflow-x:hidden to the body it will do the trick :)

Comment: Its fine, but I need overflow-x for body, my site have minimum width 1024px.. I'll try edit your code and find solution..

Comment: Then apply a container to wrap everything and apply overflow-x: hidden to it. :)

Comment: @CroaToa also you can use `overflow-x:hidden;` for body to get what you desire

Comment: This is what i suggested him earlier but he said he cannot apply to the body that's why i told him to wrap everything into another container :)

Comment: All the same, I can scroll your demo horizontaly.. On site I dont need that.. Click the mouse wheel and move right.

Comment: I want something like that, http://bpoyandjo.com/collections/neck-statements but for my markup, if I change markup I'll lost much time and code ( Is that impossible to set position fixed on click, and return position static on undo-click with animation?

Comment: Just change the position in the CSS classes i edited. I created a class .hide and .show to be added respectively to .content (.content.hide) and to .hidden-content (.hidden-content.show). Modify the CSS properties of these classes (.content.hide and .hidden-content.show) to achieve the result you need.

Comment: It would be polite at this point that you would at least accept the answer though...

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `$(".content").css('position', 'static');` from the undo handler then it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but I no need position:fixed anymore when clicked undo-click

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Fiddle, I commented out some code and set a z-index to content to make it always appear on top.

```
$('.undo-click').click(function(){
$(".content").css('position', 'fixed');
$(".content").css('left', '0px');
   $(".hidden-content").css('position', "fixed");
//    $(".hidden-content").css('visibility', 'hidden');
//$(".hidden-content").css('opacity', '0');
$(".hidden-content").css('right', '-300px');
// $(".hidden-content").css('width', '0px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q283G/3/

Comment: Thanks, but I no need position:fixed anymore when clicked undo-click

Comment: @CroaToa Then change the position to whatever you like, it still works, I will post an update. Edited:okay it doesn't work with static, hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

here is the better way without changing your previous markups: http://jsfiddle.net/q283G/8/

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $('.content').css('position','fixed');
    $('.content').animate({left:'-300px'},500);
    $('.hidden-content').animate({marginLeft:'-300px'},500);
});

$('.undo-click').click(function(){
    $('.content').animate({left:'0px'},500);
    $('.hidden-content').animate({marginLeft:'0px'},500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.content').css('position','static');
    },500);
});
```

Comment: It's not a good way to use js to edit css properties. Instead it's more performing to add a class with CSS properties and toggle it. :)

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you because it will work anyway, but it's not the best way the way you are doing it.

Comment: @AlexIncarnati thank you for you opinion, but sometimes it is needed and is necessary to change the CSS without using classes! sometimes it is impossible to change the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Sure totally agree, thanks for accepting my feedback. It's nice of you. :)

Comment: again I must mention that your way is more efficient in terms of being neat and readable, and being easy-to-use or edit later on. after all we're all here to learn new things and listen to each other's ideas, right? :)

Comment: Sure Amin, it is. and Thanks for pointing it out. Simpler is always better in all terms and in this case also performance wise. :)

Comment: I want something like that, http://bpoyandjo.com/collections/neck-statements but for my markup, if I change markup I'll lost much time and code ( Is that impossible to set position fixed on click, and return position static on undo-click with animation?

Comment: @CroaToa that is what the code does, on click the position becomes fixed, and on undo the position becomes static

Answer (score 0):

try this...

create new css file ( new-content and new-hidden-content)

```
content
{
       ........
}

newcontent //example implementation
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -300px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: blue;
}
new-hidden-content
{
   .........
}
```

and set new class for each item like this:

```
    document.getElementById("#").className = "newcontent";
```

OR:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName(".content").................
```

and:
this way better than ,your js implementation.